# Python environment variables using Django

Tags: python, django, variables, operating-system, environment

I am currently implementing a system of secret key management using environment variables on development and production machines, however I have run into an inconsistency with os.environ.get()

This does not work: `ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

This however does work:

```
SECRET_KEY = str(os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY'))
```

why is this? any insight? It is returned as a string object with the same value both ways..

thanks!

Comment: What is error in the first code snippet?

Comment: well there is no error, because I am using get, but it is not able to evaluate `if os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` as true unless I cast it as a str. In the python shell it works fine either way.

Comment: os.environ.get() will return either string or None.

Comment: it is returning None in Django manage.py runserver, but returning the string in the shell

Comment: os.environ - show all your environment variables

Comment: You forget to close the SECRET_KEY String too.

Comment: that was a typo sorry. but it is indeed showing the variable in os.environ

Comment: I am getting specifically: `ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

Comment: @user2016117 Can you be more clear on your problem? The "ImproperlyConfigured" error should be related to the value of SECRET_KEY in settings.py: check you don't have any error there or it is just empty or even not defined. Also note that `str(None)` returns `"None"`, which evaluates to `True`.

Comment: you are correct, that is what is happening. Silly me. `os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` works fine, while os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY']` does not. I am not sure why this is, but please put your response as an answer and I will gladly accept it as that was the error! Thanks!